# Nginx proxy server not serving static assets on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I followed some answers here did the changes to the `location` block to serve the static assets. Seems no luck.

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

  location ~* /(assets|fonts|swfs|images)/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

}
```

Can someone please help me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Your `location` syntax is incorrect. You are using a regular expression which requires the `~` or `~*` operator. The `^~` operator means something else. See [manual here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Comment: Changed it to `location ~* /(assets|fonts|swfs|images)` but still no assets are loading

Comment: do you get any erros ?

Comment: @GorillaApe no I m not getting any errors. Nginx error log is empty. The page proxy page loads but without any assets contents.

Comment: I am getting console errors on the browser `404 not found` for css and js

Answer (score 0):

If your assets' folders are inside `/var/www/html`, for example `/var/www/html/images/test.jpg`, you want to use this syntax:

```
location ^~ /(assets|fonts|swfs|images)/ {
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/test.com.access_proxy.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/test.com.error_proxy.log;
    root       /var/www/html/;
    internal;
}
```